# Python expection indentation on nonexisting line

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pycharm, discord, indentation

I am so confused. I am trying to make a Discord bot using Python and Discord.py.
I have literally copied the example code from [here](https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/discord-py/setup/) and am now getting this error:

```
  File "C:/Users/****/Documents/Discord/RTSC/J'alami/bot.py", line 27
client.run(TOKEN)
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Now here's the weird thing. As you can see from my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
client.run("{this string is secret}")
```

There are only 3 lines, by far not 27 as the error says.
I am very new to Python so I might be missing something obvious here.
My IDE is PyCharm 2020.1.1 Community Edition

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you checked whether just the import statement works fine?

Comment: Also, triple-check you're not mixing spaces and tabs (python doesn't like that)

Comment: This is driving me nuts. After commenting out every line (even the blank ones) it still gives me the error. How? There's no code right?

Comment: The error happens when the file is empty...

Comment: You mean you run something like ```python empty.py``` in your envivonment with ```empty.py``` being an empty file and you still get the indent-error with a reference to a line number?

Comment: Update! After running the code from command prompt instead of PyCharm I am now indeed getting the error of an invalid module. I'm now gonna try to find out how it doesn't recognize it as I have installed it with pip. I think this was a problem with PyCharm and not with the code. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: The reason that this is weird is that the same import statement worked in a different script.